# Cannot get Vim to remap CTRL+S to `:w`

Tags: bash, vim, gnome-terminal

I've been trying to get Vim to remap <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or ^S) to `:w` by editing my `.vimrc` file, however  it doesn't work.

This is my current `~/.vimrc` configuration:

```
nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>
imap <c-s> <Esc><c-s>
```

I read that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> can run a command which freezes the terminal, however I don't seem to experience this.

If I do press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, nothing happens. If I then do <kbd>ESC</kbd> and `:q` I'm informed that I haven't already saved changes.

`:current` tells me that `user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the whole `<C-a>` -> `<C-z>` range, `<C-s>` and `<C-q>` are the only two that can't be mapped in CLI Vim because they are intercepted before they reach the editor.

What they are meant to be used for, flow control, is mostly an artefact of the relatively long history of terminals and networked computing and not really relevant today.

The simplest way to get back the full alphabet for your Ctrl mappings is to add this line to your `*rc`:

```
stty -ixon
```

Comment: Thanks- I had that at the very end of my `.bashrc` moved it to the top and CTRL<S works.

Comment: Though there may be applications that require terminal flow control (CTRL-S). Just something to be aware of in case of problems.

Comment: I haven't come across any before, hopefully I won't though.